# Join two columns and add a consecutive number at the end, but only when there's a certain text in one of the columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have three columns (cross_type, parent_cross_ID, and transplant_ID). I want to join the cross_type and parent_cross_ID columns, but I want to add a consecutive number at the end (behind either an underscore or a period). I have five crosstypes and am only keeping one type that would require this so I want it to generate a specific transplant_ID only when the cross_type column is one of the five crosstypes.

| Transplant ID | crosstype | parent_cross_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FF_31_1 | FF | 31 |
| FF_31_2 | FF | 31 |
|  | FA | 34 |
| FF_31_3 | FF | 31 |
|  | FC | 23 |
| FF_40_4 | FF | 40 |
| FF_40_5 | FF | 40 |
|  | CF | 50 |
|  | AF | 55 |

Hopefully, that helps to visualize what I mean. When the cross is "FF", I want to generate a unique transplant ID from the crosstype column and the parent_cross_ID with a unique, but consecutive number at the end.

When there's any other crosstype, it doesn't have to generate a unique transplant_ID because I don't need anything beyond their germination location for those four crosstypes. The FF crosses are the only ones that need a unique transplant ID.

I've tried using some combinations of "join", "sequence" and "if", but it keeps giving me back errors so I must be doing something wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your data don't have anything that uniquely identifies each row's data.  The solutions apply the numbering based on the current sort order. This may cause problems for you in the future. Without unique identifiers for each row's data, changing the order will re-apply the numbers differently, and the original order can't be restored. The [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173213) and [my own](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173214) would be slightly different if there was a unique identifier in the data (e.g. entry date, ID etc.)

Comment: There's actually more columns - I have a unique identifier based on where they are on a soil grid when the seeds are sown. I just don't need that for the transplant ID because their grid location will correspond to the transplant ID (if that makes sense).

Comment: [I added an example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173214) that uses a unique ID to keep the Transplant ID's associated with the correct data row regardless of the order of the rows.  The order of the Transplant ID assigned is tied to the  Crosstrype and the unique ID rather than the current sort order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
=arrayformula(let(
crosstype,tocol(B2:B,1),
parent_cross_ID,tocol(C2:C,1),
uniquenumber,reduce(tocol(,1),crosstype,lambda(acc,arr,{acc;if(arr="FF",max(acc)+1,)})),if(uniquenumber,crosstype&"_"&parent_cross_ID&"_"&uniquenumber,)))
```

We are using `reduce` to increment a counter by 1 each time *crosstype*=FF (or return null if false) and assigning this to the variable *uniquenumber*. We are then using `if` to check the values of *uniquenumber*, and where they are truthy (i.e. the non-nulls) to create a unique ID as per the example table.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Variation using SCAN and BYROW

```
=LET(data, QUERY(B2:C, "Where B is not Null", 0),
   ffs, ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(data,,1)="FF"),
   BYROW({data, SCAN(,ffs, LAMBDA(a,n, a+n))},
     LAMBDA(r, IF(INDEX(r,,1)="FF",JOIN("-", r),))))
```

To move the formula above the data rows, you can add the heading label `"Transplant ID"` into the formula:

```
=LET(data, QUERY(B2:C, "Where B is not Null", 0),
   ffs, ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(data,,1)="FF"),
   { "Transplant ID";
     BYROW({data, SCAN(,ffs, LAMBDA(a,n, a+n))},
     LAMBDA(r, IF(INDEX(r,,1)="FF",JOIN("-", r),))) })
```

## Functions

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) [SCAN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094?hl=en)

## Explanation

1. `data` contains the rows with a value in `B2:B`
2. `ffs` is a column of TRUE/FALSE values matching rows containing the string `"FF"`
3. BYROW passes each row of a three-column array, one by one, into a LAMDA function, which stores the current row in `r`. Columns 1-2 are `data`, and Column 3 is a SCAN function that returns the intermediary values of an accumulator `a`, incremented for each row by a number `n` where `n=1` if `ffs=TRUE`, otherwise `n=0`.
4. The LAMBDA's formula tests if the value in `r` at Column 1 is "FF":

   - `if_true` JOIN is applied to `r` delimited by a hyphen `-`.
   - `if_false` a blank value is returned

## Variation Using a Unique ID

This will tie the Transplant ID's to the row data's ID, meaning the Transplant IDs will not change each time the order of rows changes.

- New IDs should always be unique and greater than all previous IDs
- Rows that are assigned Transplant IDs should not be deleted (the non-tagged rows can be deleted) or it will change the order.

```
=LET(rng,B2:D,
  data,SORT({FILTER(B2:D, LEN(B2:B)),
    SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B))},2,1,3,1),
  ffs,ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(data,,1)="FF"),
   {"Transplant ID"; 
    SORT(BYROW({data, SCAN(,ffs, LAMBDA(a,n, a+n))},
      LAMBDA(r, IF(INDEX(r,,1)="FF",
        JOIN("-", CHOOSECOLS(r,1,2,5)),))),
      INDEX(data,,4),1)})
```

[image: Formula shows how sort does not change the Transplant ID when there is a unique ID]